# Isn't SSG of NextJS is very memory consuming Due to generation of static files

Tags: memory-management, next.js, ssg, pre-rendering

Actually every one likes to pre-render by SSG process due to its fastness in next by setting fallback to true and revalidation key on! But the problem is if I have 10000 html product pages and 10000 html files will be generated and so on! Doesn't by passage of time it will be very much memory consuming when pages increases more and more ! So Doesn't SSG becomes very costly in long term to put lots of file when our website is getting bigger ?As I am new to next I am quite worried that do I really need to store 1000 product id pages just to give user a better experience as my datas in product pages will not change very frequently!